# fp-ts flow/pipe but output is "merged" with input as each function is called

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, fp-ts

I'm trying to write a library where the input is an Array of functions where the output of each function is merged in with its input and then passed into the next function.

Basically similar to `compose/flow/pipe`, but the input is always a single object and the output only specifies new properties.

EG:

```
(A) -> B, 
(A & B) -> C,
(A & B & C) -> D
...
```

I was able to accomplish this, but I'm sure there must be a "cleaner" more functional way to do it with `fp-ts`:

[Working Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-forked-tzpitd?file=/src/index.ts)

NOTES:

- The caller cannot be responsible for the "merging" the input and output.  I need a interface that accepts the collection of functions in the form where each only returns it's component part.
- The input of functions must be type-safe, and ideally forgiving (declaring function that takes `(A & B & C)` with only `(A & C)` should not throw a type error.

Comment: Typing `flow` with no overloads is already kind of hard and ugly, and you are still limited to a certain number of generics, but this sliding window of intersections on top would most probably mess up type inference. I think you should stick with this implementation. You may be able to factorise some code but that's about it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your code correctly, you're looking for the so-called `Do` notation (or `bind`/`bindTo`, take your pick of what exactly to use) with the Identity monad (since you aren't working with Option/Either/etc.).

```js
const y = mergeFlow(
  (ctx: { input: string }) => ({ length: ctx.input.length }),
  ({ length }) => ({ isTooLong: length > 5 }),
  ({ isTooLong, input }) => ({
    trimmed: isTooLong ? input.slice(0, 5) : input
  }),
  ({ trimmed, length }) => ({ difference: length - trimmed.length })
);
```

would be

```js
import { bind, bindTo } from 'fp-ts/Identity'

const x = (ctx: { input: string }) => pipe(
  ctx,
  bindTo('ctx'),
  bind('length', ({ ctx }) => ctx.input.length),
  bind('isTooLong', ({ length }) => length > 5),
  bind('trimmed', ({ isTooLong, ctx: { input } }) => isTooLong ? input.slice(0, 5) : input),
  bind('difference', ({ length, trimmed }) => length - trimmed.length)
)
```

Note that if you could write this in TypeScript

```js
bindTo('ctx')<{ctx: { input: string }}>,
bind(...)
```

then you could use `flow` instead of `pipe` and write this:

```js
const x = flow(
  bindTo('ctx'),
  bind('length', ...),
  ...
)
```

and not bother with hard-coding the `(ctx: { input: string }) => ...` in the function definition.

In any case, type of `x` is

```js
(ctx: { input: string }) => ({
  readnly ctx: { input: string },
  readonly length: number,
  readonly isTooLong: boolean,
  readonly trimmed: string,
  readonly difference: string,
})
```

Because the keys are `readonly`, you shouldn't be able to modify any of them, only add new props like you asked.